# what does m<|x| imply?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

I know $|x|\le M \ \implies -M\le x \le M$ but what does $m\le|x|$ imply?

Can I just plainly interpret this as $m\le x$?

and if I say $m\le x \le M$ does this still mean $-M \le x \le M$?

Comment: Are you taking $m$ and $M$ to be minima and maxima? Then by definition, $m \leq x$. Otherwise, you cannot make your proposed interpretations: $-5  \leq |-10|$ but $-5  \not \leq -10$. The last statement is also false for $M<0$.

Comment: The answer to "Can I" is **no**, unless you happen to know that $x$ is positive (which makes it redundant to take an absolute value, doesn't it?). For the last part, if $m \geq -M$ then $m\leq x \leq M$ implies $-M\leq x \leq M$, but $-M\leq x \leq M$ does not necessarily imply $m\leq x \leq M$. Maybe you should share the problem that caused you to ask these questions; you might have some misconception that someone can help with.

Comment: There is no problem that caused this misconception...I was just brushing up on some mathematics....and when I tried to interpret this in different situations....I got this question...anyways the answer posted here are more than convincing...thanks a lot @David K

Comment: Thanks a lot  @epsilon emperor

Comment: It's fine as a generic question. Glad it worked out.

Comment: @Orpheus Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming $m > 0$. $|x| \ge m$ implies $x \ge m$ or $x \le - m$. To see this, I recommend you consider $m = 2$ and look at the following graph. The red curve is $y = |x|$ and the blue horizontal line is $y = 2$, positioned $2$ units above the $X$-axis.

[image]

If $|x| \le 2$, you're looking at the region (line segment) on the $X$-axis which is contained between the points $-2$ and $2$. This is clear from the picture. If $|x| \ge 2$, you're looking at two rays, one going to $\infty$ and another to $-\infty$, emanating from $2$ and $-2$ respectively. Hope this helps.

Comment: And if $m \leq 0,$ then $|x|\geq m$ for all real numbers $x.$ You could say you're still looking at a ray going to $\infty$ and a ray going to $-\infty,$ but in the case $m\leq 0$ the two rays overlap and cover the entire number line.